# Problem in CNY70 sensor

Tags: sensor

I want to use a CNY 70 reflective optical sensor to turn on a LED.
The CNY70 has an IR LED whose light is detected by a phototransistor after being reflected from a "target".

[image]

When I connect Vcc and Gnd, I can be sure that the transmitter works(because cellphone camera detects it) but it won't turn on the LED in any case.
Where is the problem?
**Please provide a schematic for this purpose**
Link to datasheet:
http://www.sandorobotics.com/attachments/cny70seguidor_de_linea.pdf

Comment: What is a CNY70 sensor? Link to a datasheet please. Is this it? [Vishay CNY70](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83751/cny70.pdf)

Comment: Yes. Vishay CNY 70

Comment: How did you hook it up? Show a schematic diagram.

Comment: -1 for expecting everyone to just know whatever this "CNY70" thing is, and not even providing a link to the datasheet.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I updated my post

Comment: Show a schematic diagram.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - I knew what a CNY70 is. That should be enough :-) [ :-) :-) :-) ../. ]

Comment: I'll provide my schematic as soon as I can

Answer (score 2):

The CNY70 does not turn on your LED because you are using it wrongly,
OR because it is dead :-).
 I know this because I have used them occasionally since long long long ago and they do work.

Some points to note:

- Get the polarity correct. Note that input and output polaritoes are "opposite".
- The output current is going to be small - probably under 1 mA. Your LED needs to work OK at the current level you achieve. The graph below shows Iout for 20 mA Iin at various reflector distances. At a zero distance you get about 1 mA out (5% current transfer ratio), and at 5mm you get less than 0.2 mA.
- You need enough output voltage to allow for LED voltage drop + optocoupler output voltage drop. A look at figures 6 & 8 in the data sheet show that at 20 mA drive you need about 10 Volts drop across the output transistor [!!!!!] to get 1 mA (5%) output.

For most practical purposes this device is not going to do a good job of driving an LED directly. Using it to turn on an external output transistor will give a vastly better result.

[image]